# Random-walk in a pentacle (5 nodes)

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk

There are a total of 5 nodes at the edge of a pentagram [image]

At each node, you have a 4 choices which will lead you to either a destination node or non-destination node. Assume the decision of path is indepedent of your previous decision, and all decision has to be made random. What is the expected number of node you have to visit, in order to reach to your destination node?

Please give me hint instead of answer

Comment: Please give me hint instead of providing answer

Comment: But I am thinking that, you could possibly stuck in a infinite loop (never reach destination)

Comment: Can you start at the destination node? If you do, are you done (i.e., does this trip involve only the starting node), or do you make a move to another random node?

Comment: The probability of never reaching is zero. @kou

Comment: Assuming  you don't get to the destination on your first step, what is the expected number of steps after that?

Comment: no, you dont start at the destination node (assume)

Comment: Clarification: Are we looking for the expected number of steps, or the expected number of nodes visited with multiple visits to the same node only counting once?

Comment: expected number of steps

Comment: the answer is 4

Comment: Another hint: You have probably seen the relevant fact before.

Comment: Why the lack of reaction to the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with irreducible HMC since the graph given is irreducible. From the property of local balance of we can calculate the value of stationary distribution $\Gamma $ & the entries in it are reciprocal of the expected time to reach the corresponding state back. Here time is synonymous to number of nodes we visit in our journey. A brief hint & workout will be as follows:
Denote the time as : $ T_0 $ = inf{$n \ge 0 : X_n = 0 $ } [Denoting my destination node as 0 - just numbering - you can choose whatever you want].
What we want is then $E_0[T_0]$ i.e. expectation value of the time it takes to reach back my starting node. From the theory of invariants we can calculate $\Gamma$ as $\Gamma(i) = x_i/\Sigma_i x_i $. From the condition of local balance you can calculate the terms $\Gamma[i]$ and hence $\Gamma[0] = x_0/\Sigma_i x_i$. Basically it can be shown easily that $\Sigma_i x_i=E_0[T_0]$ and since we started with state 0, $x_o=1$. Hence, the required quantity is reciprocal of $\Gamma[0]$.

Answer that I got : $E_0[T_0]=5$.